# The function transforming a vector to its corresponding bilinear form is a functional

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am reading the book "Linear Algebra", written by Serge Lang and got a small stackle in Exercise 6, page 219. It is as the following.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{K}$, and let $g$ be a bilinear form on $V$, written $<,>$.
Show that for each $w \in V$, the map $L_w : v \rightarrow <v,w>$ is a functional $L_w$ on $V$.

I would like to prove that $<v,w> = \overline{<v,w>}$, but there is no idea to do that.

Could you please give me a hint?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A functional is just a map from $V$ to $\mathbb K$. So, $L_w$ is obviously a functional. I guess they meant "linear functional". So, you only have to prove that this thing is linear (which is trivially induced by the linearity of the bilinear form in the first component).

Comment: What does $\overline{\langle v, w \rangle}$ mean for a vector space over an arbitrary field $\Bbb K$?  Also, what's a stackle?

Comment: I confuse when $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{C}$, then the value $<v,w>$ may be a complex number.

Comment: But the form is not sesqui-linear. So you don't have to deal with the complex conjugate.

Comment: To say that differently: the problem does not require that the form be sesquilinear, so there's no need to look at complex conjugates.